# Keras: How to specify the first hidden cell in LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I want to use LSTM with keras for a seq2seq model: given x1... xn, output y1...yn

The question is about to compute the first hidden cell, h1, we need h0 and x1 to compute h1. As I know, we usually simply always let h0=0. There is no x0 and y0. Can we optimize h0 as well?